# How to change the application deployed in WebLogic state to Active

Tags: web-deployment, weblogic12c

I have deployed my application war file in WebLogic Server(WebLogic ServerAdministration Console 12c) in the deployments section. After deploying the distribution I can see the application is in ***Prepared*** state and it's not changing to ***Active*** state.

Sometime it is in ***distribute Initializing*** state and not changing again to active state if I activate the changes on the console page. Usually I update the war file and it will be changed to Active state once it is deployed successfully.

How to fix the above issue as I don't see any issues in the logs too?

Answer (score 0):

Once the War is deployed and available in the distribute Initializing state I start the application to servicing all the requests and it changed to Active state.

[image]

Now it's up and running and I'm able to access the application.